# How to call api within map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hi im trying to do an api call within a map, however it just returns as an object.promise. Is there away to call api within it without it returning as an object.promise

````
const MatchHistory = ({ history }) => {
    const Match=[];


      return (
        <div>
          <p>
           {history.map( hist => (
            axios.get('https://polar-hollows-37538.herokuapp.com/matchdata/'+hist.gameId).then(response => (Match.push(response.data.platformId))),
            console.log('get:'+axios.get('https://polar-hollows-37538.herokuapp.com/matchdata/'+hist.gameId).then(response =>(Match.push(response.data.mapId)))),
            <Card>
              <img src={'img\\'+hist.lane+'.png'}></img>
              <li key={hist.gameId}>
              <h5 className="card-title1">Lane:{hist.lane}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Role:{hist.role}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">Champion:{hist.champion}</h5> 
              <h5 className="card-title1">GameId:{hist.gameId}</h5>
              </li>
            </Card>
      ))}}
        </p> 
      </div> 
   )
  }```
````

Comment: can you tell me your requirement to call api inside map().

Answer (score 0):

You are creating array of promises using `map`. Use `Promise.all` to resolve the array of promises.

```
const promises = history.map(hist => axios.get('https://polar-hollows-37538.herokuapp.com/matchdata/'+hist.gameId));

const Match = [];

Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(values) {
  values.forEach(value => {
      Match.push(value.data.platformId);
  })
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```